# How to prevent a plot cut off

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to extend the (right) margin of my plot:

[image: Cluster]

I tried it with `par(omi=c(10,10,5,20))` (arbitrary values) but it doesn't work.

```
par(oma=c(10,10,5,20))
ggplot(df, aes(Cluster, Number_of_observations)) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity', colour="Darkblue", fill = "skyblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label=Number_of_observations), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), 
            hjust = -0.25, vjust=-0.25) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: `par()` wouldn't work here. Try adding something like `+ expand_limits(y = 900000)` to your ggplot code.

Comment: `par` is a base plot command. Doesn't have any effect with ggplot

Comment: @Z.Lin Thank you, that works! Can you please post your advice as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer, as requested, & expanding on it to justify it being an answer :)

As @RichardTelford noted, `par` works with the base plotting commands, as it sets parameters for the graphical device. Each subsequent plot-related command makes some change on the device. For example, `points` draws points at the specified coordinates, `text` adds text strings, etc. Things are done sequentially. An earlier command (such as `par`) affects a later command, but not vice versa.

`ggplot2` works differently. The `ggplot(...) + geom_XXX(...) + scale_XXX(...) + theme(...)` commands create a ggplot **object**. Except for `ggplot(...)`, which initializes the object & must come first, the order for other parts can be switched around with no real impact to the result (though maintaining some order would make your code easier to read). This means that to affect the appearance for any part of a plot created through `ggplot2`, you have to make the change *within* its commands, not outside using `par`.

In your case, the following would work:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Cluster, Number_of_observations)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge', colour = "Darkblue", fill = "skyblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Number_of_observations), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), 
            hjust = -0.25, vjust = -0.25) + 
  expand_limits(y = 900000) + # or some other arbitrarily large number
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

I also recommend using `geom_col(...)` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity", ...)`. They are equivalent, but the former requires less typing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with `expand_limits`.
See;
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/expand_limits.html

Comment: this was suggested already in the comments

Comment: thanks, you're right. I missed looking into it.